# testng tests run programmatically not get reported in testng reports

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, integration-testing, testng

My Scenario

1. Log in to my application.
2. Navigate to the page provided by data provider
3. Run control test cases on this page
4. continue step 2 and 3 till all the pages from data provider has been tested.

My Flow :

1. Navigate to the page
2. I have some 40 odd control test classes. Their working : At run time fetch control(respective control test class e.g combo box, text box etc..) and perform tests on those control one by one for the current page then move on to next page.

My approach :

1. Created a @Test for navigating to different pages. It accepts different pages from dataprovider.
2. Inside that test i am calling my other control test classes.

My problem:

1. I am only able to see test results of my navigation test in testNG report. what happen of my other test results which have ran for all those pages? where are those test results  logged.

Code snippets:
Here @Test testWrapper() is my navigation test which accepts navigation data provider.

```
public class WrapperTest 
{
    @Test
    public void testWrapper()
    {
        //Approach no. 1
        /*TestNG test=new TestNG();
        test.setTestClasses(new Class[]{test1.class,test2.class});
        test.run();*/

        //Approach no. 2
        XmlSuite xmlSuite=new XmlSuite();
        List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites=new ArrayList<>();
        XmlTest t1xmlTest=new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
        XmlTest t2xmlTest=new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
        XmlClass t1xmlClass=new XmlClass(test1.class);
        XmlClass t2xmlClass=new XmlClass(test2.class);
        List<XmlClass> test1ClassList=new ArrayList<>();
        List<XmlClass> test2ClassList=new ArrayList<>();
        test1ClassList.add(t1xmlClass);
        test2ClassList.add(t2xmlClass);
        t1xmlTest.setXmlClasses(test1ClassList);
        t2xmlTest.setXmlClasses(test2ClassList);
        xmlSuites.add(xmlSuite);
        TestNG test=new TestNG();
        test.setXmlSuites(xmlSuites);
        test.run();
    }
}
```

Control test snippets:

```
public class test1
{
    @Test
    public void f1()
    {
        System.out.println("running test1.f1");
        assert true;
    }

    @Test
    public void f2()
    {
        System.out.println("running test1.f2");
        assert true; 
    }
}

public class test2
{
    @Test
    public void f1()
    {
        System.out.println("runnin test2.f1");
        assert true;
    }

    @Test
    public void f2()
    {
        System.out.println("runnin test2.f2");
        assert true;
    }
}
```

Assume `test1` and `test2` classes are my control classes.
Where am i going wrong. Or is there something else which i need to implement to get my desired test results.

[**Note** : My tests are running as expected it is just the reporting part which is not in order].

Comment: Why do you have your instantiation of TestNG inside a @Test?  Is it possible that a different instance of TestNG is the one running and reporting?  Could you instantiate TestNG in main()?

Comment: Hi MrTi you are absolutely correct. as soon as i had set the output directory for my TestNG instance, i saw that it was another TestNG instance running underlying my test. A seperate report got generated for my underlying test. i had tried instantiating the TestNG instance inside main method. but the problem is as i am adding the control tests inside the navigation test. they are not getting executed and i am getting exception as : java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next

Comment: I don't have experience with instantiating TestNG.  I simply use `@Test`, and not worry about the other details, so I don't know what you are running into.

Comment: You shud include the two classes in your testng xml directly rather than through wrapper..